# Data is not loaded in to Datatable using Jsp Ajex crud

Tags: java, jsp

i am creating simple crud system.i am beginner of jsp.i can add data into the database using ajax in JSP record added successfully.after add the record i tried to load the data on datatable but data is not loading on datatable 
i written code below. what i tried so far

**Table**

```
 <table id="tbl-projects" class="table table-responsive table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>

                </table>



  ********JQuery********

<Script>
get_all();
    function get_all()
        {
            $('#tbl-projects').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $.ajax({
                url : "all_project.jsp",
                type : "GET",
                dataType : "JSON",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#tbl-projects').html(data);
                    $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                        "aaData": data,
                        "scrollX": true,
                        "aoColumns": [
                            {"sTitle": "StudentName", "mData": "name"},
                            {"sTitle": "Course", "mData": "course"},
                            {"sTitle": "Fee", "mData": "fee"},                
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Edit",
                                "mData": "id",
                                "render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
                                    return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick="get_project_details(' + mData + ')">Edit</button>';
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Delete",
                                "mData": "id",
                                "render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
                                    return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="Remove_details(' +  mData + ')">Delete</button>';
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    });

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr);
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);

                    $.alert({
                        title: 'Fail!',
                        //            content: xhr.responseJSON.errors.product_code + '<br>' + xhr.responseJSON.msg,
                        type: 'red',
                        autoClose: 'ok|2000'
                    });
                    $('#save').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#save').html('');
                    $('#save').append('Save');
                }
            });
        } 
</Script>
```

**this is the Jsp code**
**all_project.jsp**   **JSP CODE**

```
    <% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
     <%
                Connection con;
                PreparedStatement pst;
                ResultSet rs;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studcrud", "root","");
                String query="select * from record";  
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                 rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while(rs.next())
                          {    
                    String id   =rs.getString("id");
                    String name   =rs.getString("name");
                    String course   =rs.getString("course");
                    String fee   =rs.getString("fee"); 

                 out.println(id);
                out.println(name);
                out.println(course);
                out.println(fee);


}                
     %>
```

**data displayed on the console look like this**

```
**1
john
java
10000
2
Raja
C#
7000
3
sad
asd
2323
4
Nishan
Jsp
12000**
```

but but display on the datatable

Add the data into the database code JSP Ajax

```
function addProject()
    {
        if($("#frmProject").valid())
        {
            var url= '';
            var dat = '';
            var method = '';
            if(isNew == true)
            {
                url = 'add.jsp';
                data = $('#frmProject').serialize();
                method = 'POST';
            }

            else
            {
                url = 'update_project.jsp';
                data = $('#frmProject').serialize() + "&project_id=" + project_id;
                method = 'POST';
            }

            $.ajax({

                type : method,
                url : url,
                dataType : 'JSON',

                success : function (data)
                {
                    $('#frmProject')[0].reset();

                    $('#save').html('');
                    $('#save').append('Add');

                    var msg;
                    get_all();
                    if(isNew)
                    {
                        msg = "Course Created";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        msg = "Course Updated";
                    }


                    isNew = true;
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr);
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);

                    $.alert({
                        title: 'Fail!',
                        //            content: xhr.responseJSON.errors.product_code + '<br>' + xhr.responseJSON.msg,
                        type: 'red',
                        autoClose: 'ok|2000'

                    });
                    $('#save').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#save').html('');
                    $('#save').append('Save');
                }

            });

        }
    }
```

**add.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>

<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


         <% 
            String studname = request.getParameter("studname");
             String course = request.getParameter("course");
             String fee = request.getParameter("fee");

            Connection con;
            PreparedStatement pst;
            ResultSet rs;

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studcrud", "root","");

            pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into records(name,course,fee)values(?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1,studname);
        pst.setString(2,course);
            pst.setString(3,fee);

            pst.executeUpdate();



        %>
```

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.10.0 of DataTables, it is built-in and easy:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.ajax.reload();
```

Or may be :

```
$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Comment: console.log i checked sir data passed successfully.but datatable not loading data. i tried your above code it is not work for me.

Comment: Can you please post full JSP code and also the place where you are calling the get_all method.

Comment: i call get_all(); method when the pages load all data display on datatable

Comment: From where you are adding the data?
I mean when you are calling server method to add the data?

Comment: You don't need to write below line :
$('#tbl-projects').html(data);

Comment: i remove but no data loaded in to the datatable sir

Comment: You can ask me any question if you have.

Comment: yes. i have a question. i am using json. when the page is load get call the fuction getall(); inside the getall() i wrote the ajex function get data from all_project.jsp page. but data passing through json format. how to pass into Datatable. data coming successfully i tested through console.log.